# Git installation failed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd, upstart, git

I am trying to install git on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but  am getting the following error.

Command:

```
$ sudo apt install git
```

Error:

```
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure it's updated using following command,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after that install Git using,

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

and check installation using following command

```
git --version
```